# copy/paste in terminator stop working after a while

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome-terminator

I am running Ubuntu 16 and has Terminator installed, for some strange reason copy/paste either through keyboard shortcut or right-click mouse menu would stop working on certain terminator windows, it would still work on other terminator windows when this happens, the only way that I can fix this is to restart the bad terminator window. Anyone else experience this and is there a quick fix for it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using GNU `screen` or `tmux` or `byobu` or any other [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer)? Does middle click pasting (select text, then middle click to paste it) work?

Comment: No, I am not using any of the terminal multiplexer, middle click pasting does not work either for that window.

Comment: Same issue here: I have been using Terminator for a year no problem but today the copy paste is not working: shift-ctrl-c, shift-insert, context menu, no go. I can copy from other windows and paste into terminal, but cannot copy anything from terminal into itself or any other window, it's literally like the copy operation does nothing. Starting a new terminal did not fix the problem, I had to restart the machine (maybe logout/in would have worked but that's not much better). That it happens in new terminator windows too seems to indicate some cached info for terminator, or something in Gnome.